# Persistence Migration for Ignite

Tags: ignite

There are some wal and other db files in my server's disk if I use ignite persistence in my application. I wonder if I can copy those files onto the other server and restart ignite instance to provide service as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be possible if you set the same consistent ID (`org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration#setConsistentId`) every time.
More details could be found [here](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/distributed-persistent-store#section-usage) and [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IGNITE/Ignite+Persistent+Store+-+under+the+hood#IgnitePersistentStore-underthehood-SubfoldersGeneration)